# How to convert a list of dataUrls to one tiff or tif file in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, tiff

I'm working on a project where I need to convert a list of data URLs, each representing an image, into a single TIFF file for download using JavaScript. Currently, my code only processes the first image in the list.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
 async function handleDownload() {
    try {
        if (!fileBase64?.base64) return;

        const url = await getDataUrl();
        downloadBase64File(url);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

///

```
 async function getDataUrl() {
    try {
        const imageUrls = thumbnails.map((image) => image?.src);

        const arrayBufferList = await getArrayBufferList(imageUrls);

        const uint8ArrayList = getUint8List(arrayBufferList);


        const blob = new Blob([...uint8ArrayList], {
            type: "image/" + fileBase64?.type,
        });


        const dataUrl = getDataUrlFromBlob(blob);


        return dataUrl;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        setIsSpinning(false);
        setProgress(null);
    }
}
```

///

```
   async function getArrayBufferList(imageUrls) {
    const IFDs = [];
    for (const image of imageUrls) {
        const dataURL = image?.src;
        const result = await fetch(dataURL);
        if (!result.ok) {
            throw new Error(
                `Failed to fetch image: ${result.status} ${result.statusText}`
            );
        }
        const ifd = await result.arrayBuffer();
        IFDs.push({ ...image, ifd });
    }
    return IFDs;
}
```

///

```
function getUint8List(arrayBufferList) {
    const uint8ArrayList = [];

    for (const arrayBuffer of arrayBufferList) {
        const bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        uint8ArrayList.push(bytes);
    }
    return uint8ArrayList;
}
```